# No module found error while importing python file from another folder while executing in terminal(command Prompt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, command-prompt, python-import

I can import methods

```
# ~/main/main.py
from my_utils import get_logger, get_driver
...
```

in other python file inside the same folder.

```
# ~/main/my_utils.py
def get_logger:
....
def get_driver:
...
```

I want to know if it is possible to import file in different folder

```
# ~/main/main.py
from sub.my_utils import get_logger, get_driver # this is ok in eclipse, but has error in command line
...
```

something like:

```
# ~/sub/my_utils.py
def get_logger:
....
def get_driver:
...
```

There is `__init__.py` file, but I got error in command line, though eclipse is ok.

```
from sub.my_utils import get_logger, get_driver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub'`
```

Comment: Also [Importing from sub-folder hierarchy in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/11501870)

Comment: add `__init__.py` to each directory you import from, although I would create a directory for the entire program, then make subdirectories for modules, don't make module directories in your home dir and try to import from there as that could be messy.

Comment: I put file `__init__.py` in sub folder, though it is ok in eclipse, but not in command line! I appended error.